# SELECT suppliers with products in stock but not in the catalogue

Tags: mysql, subquery

To check a Mysql database after importing some data I need to do the following:

**Database description:**
2tables Products and Suppliers

1. Products with Name, SupplierID,
   ManufactYear,StockQty,CatalogueRef(order in the catalogue),HiddenProductFlag(true mean
   product is hidden and not exposed in the catalogue)
2. Suppliers with Name and HiddenSupplierFlag (true mean supplier is hidden and  not
   exposed in the catalogue)

I want to find the list of suppliers with HiddenSupplierFlag false from which we have Not any hidden product exposed in the catalogue (CatalogueRef >0) but still have some in stock whith their HiddenProductFlag false and whatever is the ManufactYear.

I guess I should use some subqueries but I'm a total noob about them...
Any suggestion will help

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

You need a column in suppliers for their id (primary key), so that you can reference that table from the SupplierID column in the Products table. Then you can do the following:

SELECT suppliers.name
FROM suppliers
WHERE suppliers.hiddensupplierflag = false
AND suppliers.id IN (Select SupplierID
FROM products
WHERE products.HiddenProductFlag = false
AND products.CatalogueRef > 0
AND products.StockQty > 0
)

The inner query gets the supplier ids for products that are valid (referenced in catalogue, stock quantity > 0, etc...) and then you are getting their names from the supplier table by matching the id with the ids returned from the inner query.

Comment: The cure looks worse than the disease